# Why are Iterators notated as value objects, but referenced as pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

In the C++ Standard Map Library, a call to the iteration functions returns an iterator pointer,

```
std::map<int, int> map;
std::map<int, int>::iterator ite = map.find(1);
```

But, when the iterator is used, it must be accessed as a pointer variable,

```
int first = ite->first;
int second = ite->second;
```

Why is this the case when we are putting the obtained value from the `find` function into a non-pointer. Shouldn't the correct syntax be:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator *pIte = map.find(1)
```

or if using the original syntax,

```
int first = ite.first;
int second = ite.second;
```

since we are obtaining a value, and not a pointer from the function's return value? It is also not clarified in the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/). Why is this the case?

Comment: iterators *act* as pointers, and in some cases are pointers. Your suggested syntax is a pointer to an iterator.

Comment: the same you have with `shared` and `unique_ptr` they are objects which should act like pointers so this is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jaggedSpire suggested, iterators are supposed to act like ptrs, having defined the operators `*, ->, etc`. But the thing is, an iterator isn't an explicit pointer. The syntax you suggested:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator *pIte = map.find(1);
```

Is a pointer to an iterator, not just an iterator. The reason when you wrote:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator pIte = map.find(1);
```

you have to write: `ite->first` is because `operator->` is defined for iterators. This means that iterators are supposed to act like pointers.

Comment: Ok, so it is actually not a pointer, just a value type that acts like one. I still don't understand why it is implemented this way, but I get how it works now.

Comment: Here is some further reading @iamseiko: http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterator-define.html

Comment: That helps. According to it, iterators are just a typedef of their corresponding Object pointers, which makes a lot more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The call of the function

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator ite = map.find(1);
```

returns iterator that behaves like pointers.

So you need to use the syntax of accessing objects using pointers

```
int first = ite->first;
int second = ite->second;
```

Or you could write instead

```
int first = ( *ite ).first;
int second = ( *ite ).second;
```

Compare for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    std::pair<int, int> a[N] = { { 2, 2 }, { 4, 4 }, { 1, 1 }, { 3, 3 }, { 5, 5 } };

    std::pair<int, int> *it = std::find( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::make_pair( 1, 1 ) );

    if ( it != std::end( a ) )
    {
        std::cout << it - a << ": "
                  << "{ " << it->first << ", " << it->second << " }" << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2: { 1, 1 }
```

Here `it` is explicitly declared like a pointer.